# Automapper error: Expressions mapping from methods not supported yet

Tags: automapper

Any idea what might cause the error "Expressions mapping from methods not supported yet." when trying to map two objects? I cannot find any reference to this error anywhere.

EDITED---

I have more information.  I have a property in my DTO declared as:

```
 public LookupItem RegionType { get; set; }
```

However, when I invoke the mapping, it generates the error, "Expressions mapping from methods not supported yet.".

However, if I change the string in the property name "Type" to anything else like "Typeo" or "ASDF", the mapping succeeds. In other words, if change the property name to "RegionTypeo".  Am I breaking any convention rules here? There seems to be something wrong with including the string "Type" in my property name.

Below is the generated error:

Result Message:

```
Test method Rep.Tests.PlanServiceTest.GetBuildings threw exception: 
System.NotImplementedException: Expressions mapping from methods not supported yet.
Result StackTrace: 
at AutoMapper.PropertyMap.ResolveExpression(Type currentType, Expression instanceParameter)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMemberBindings(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, Type typeIn, TypeMap typeMap, Expression instanceParameter)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, Type typeIn, Type typeOut, Expression instanceParameter)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, Type typeIn, Type typeOut)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass12.<CreateMapExpression>b__0(TypePair tp)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
at AutoMapper.Internal.DictionaryFactoryOverride.ConcurrentDictionaryImpl2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression[TSource,TDestination](IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ProjectionExpression1.ToTResult
at Rep.Services.PlanService.GetBuildings() in c:\Dev\REP\Rep\Services\PlanService.cs:line 369
at Rep.Tests.PlanServiceTest.GetBuildings() in c:\Dev\REP\Rep.Tests\PlanServiceTest.cs:line 50
```

Comment: Does your code uses custom member resolvers?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "string in the property name". Could you also post your CreateMap and Map call for the DTO?

Comment: clarified. There seems to be something wrong with including the string "Type" i a property name.

Comment: i cannot reproduce the problem, please post your `CreateMap` call and `Map` call

Comment: Did you have any chance to find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/PropertyMap.cs), you can see that the exception is thrown when you try mapping functions on your objects:

```
public ExpressionResolutionResult ResolveExpression(Type currentType, Expression instanceParameter)
{
    Expression currentChild = instanceParameter;
    Type currentChildType = currentType;
    foreach (var resolver in GetSourceValueResolvers())
    {
        var getter = resolver as IMemberGetter;
        if (getter != null)
        {
            var memberInfo = getter.MemberInfo;

            var propertyInfo = memberInfo as PropertyInfo;
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                currentChild = Expression.Property(currentChild, propertyInfo);
                currentChildType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("Expressions mapping from methods not supported yet.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var oldParameter = CustomExpression.Parameters.Single();
            var newParameter = instanceParameter;
            var converter = new ConversionVisitor(newParameter, oldParameter);

            currentChild = converter.Visit(CustomExpression.Body);
            currentChildType = currentChild.Type;
        }
    }

    return new ExpressionResolutionResult(currentChild, currentChildType);
}
```

---

Based on OP clarification, I cannot reproduce the problem with the following:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string StringType { get; set; }
    public Func<Class1> FuncType { get; set; }
    public Class1 Class1Type { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string StringType { get; set; }
    public Func<Class1> FuncType { get; set; }
    public Class1 Class1Type { get; set; }
}

/* ... */
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
var c1 = new Class1() { Class1Type = new Class1(), FuncType = () => new Class1(), StringType = "Class1" };
var c2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Class1, Class2>(new Class1());
```

Comment: I have more info, I have a property in my DTO declared as: 

        public LookupItem RegionType { get; set; }

However, when I invoke the mapping, it generates the error, "Expressions mapping from methods not supported yet.". 

However, if I change the string in the property name "Type" to anything else like "Typeo" or "ASDF", the mapping succeeds.  Am I breaking any convention rules here?

Comment: @xgp Could you add this information to your question in order to benefit from a bit more space? :)